# CGMutablePathRef changing colour

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, mkoverlay

I am using the example Apple provide in one of their samples for drawing a CGPath on an MKOverlayView.  At the moment the line draws as a single colour but I would like to set this at different points along the path.

```
    - (CGPathRef)newPathForPoints:(MKMapPoint *)points
                   pointCount:(NSUInteger)pointCount
                     clipRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
                    zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
{
    // The fastest way to draw a path in an MKOverlayView is to simplify the
    // geometry for the screen by eliding points that are too close together
    // and to omit any line segments that do not intersect the clipping rect.  
    // While it is possible to just add all the points and let CoreGraphics 
    // handle clipping and flatness, it is much faster to do it yourself:
    //
    if (pointCount < 2)
        return NULL;

    CGMutablePathRef path = NULL;

    BOOL needsMove = YES;

#define POW2(a) ((a) * (a))

    // Calculate the minimum distance between any two points by figuring out
    // how many map points correspond to MIN_POINT_DELTA of screen points
    // at the current zoomScale.
    double minPointDelta = MIN_POINT_DELTA / zoomScale;
    double c2 = POW2(minPointDelta);

    MKMapPoint point, lastPoint = points[0];
    NSUInteger i;
    for (i = 1; i < pointCount - 1; i++)
    {
        point = points[i];
        double a2b2 = POW2(point.x - lastPoint.x) + POW2(point.y - lastPoint.y);
        if (a2b2 >= c2) {
            if (lineIntersectsRect(point, lastPoint, mapRect))
            {
                if (!path) 
                    path = CGPathCreateMutable();
                if (needsMove)
                {
                    CGPoint lastCGPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:lastPoint];
                    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, lastCGPoint.x, lastCGPoint.y);
                }
                CGPoint cgPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:point];
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, cgPoint.x, cgPoint.y);
            }
            else
            {
                // discontinuity, lift the pen
                needsMove = YES;
            }
            lastPoint = point;
        }
    }

#undef POW2

    // If the last line segment intersects the mapRect at all, add it unconditionally
    point = points[pointCount - 1];
    if (lineIntersectsRect(lastPoint, point, mapRect))
    {
        if (!path)
            path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        if (needsMove)
        {
            CGPoint lastCGPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:lastPoint];
            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, lastCGPoint.x, lastCGPoint.y);
        }
        CGPoint cgPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:point];
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, cgPoint.x, cgPoint.y);
    }

    return path;
}
```

Essentially on the

```
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, cgPoint.x, cgPoint.y);
```

line I would like to set an RGB colour if possible so that it can be different coloured along the way.  I would be able to do this on a CALayer with a context by using

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

But am lost if it is possible here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't possible. Stroke color is an attribute of the context, not the path; the context uses its current stroke color when you stroke the entire path. There's no way to tell the context “use this stroke color for this `lineto`, and this stroke color for this `lineto`,” etc.

You will need to keep the association between each color and each line segment on hand yourself, and stroke one segment at a time: Move to the previous point (or start point), plot a line to the next point, set the color you have for that segment, and stroke.